# Http Post string value in body

Tags: json, ajax, angular, http, post

The content-type of the Http header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

I have to POST a string value.
`environmentId: "predevnet"`

In my last project I used JQuery to make the ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        headers: this.headers,
        type: this.type,
        url: this.url,
        data: {environmentId: "predevnet"},
        dataType: this.dataType,
        contentType: this.contentType,
        async: isAsync,
        success: success,
        cache: this.cache,
        error: error
    });
```

Now I'm trying to do the same call in angular

```
return this.http
    .post(this.baseUrl + action, JSON.stringify({environmentId: "predevnet"}), options)
    .map(response => response.json() as DcResponse<T>);`
```

Result expected: The Form Data should be like this: [Result Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsNME.png)

And results I get with and without `JSON.stringify` is like this: [Current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rku1D.png)

Comment: Does it work if you set the Content-Type header to application/json?

Comment: No, I tried but it send a json object.. It have to send only the variable with its name

Comment: Have you tried to use `toString()` instead of `JSON.stringify()`?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to send only one key-value pair as a parameter in the body of the POST request, you have to omit the key part.

So if you want content-type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then your example has to be like this:

```
return this.http
    .post(this.baseUrl + action, '=predevnet', options)
    .map(response => response.json() as DcResponse<T>);`
```

Otherwise if you prefer `application/json` then you write:

```
return this.http
    .post(this.baseUrl + action, '"predevnet"', options)
    .map(response => response.json() as DcResponse<T>);`
```